# Creating Multiple GUIDs in one AMPScript Block, is this possible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sms, sendsmsactivity

I'm trying to InsertDE some data into rows to log next message conversations.

Once a user replies I want to log in a DE the initial message that started the next message conversation, the reply, and the oubound message as a result of the reply.

I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
%%[

Set @Initial_MessageJobId = GUID()
Set @Reply_MessageJobId = GUID()
Set @OB_MessageJobId = GUID()

]%%
```

Now when I test this in the email preview send context, it will generate 3 unique Guids, but as you can see in the image below, I successfully logged a row of data for each message, but the GUIDs are all identical.

[image: Here are the 3 rows of data all with the same GUID]

Comment: whast your insertde ampscript?

Comment: You genius!!! -- when I was copy pasting i pasted the same variaable 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your insertde() ampscript is using the correct var